# $O_X(D)$ sheaf of $ O_X$-modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Prove that, if $D$ is Weil divisor on variety $X$, then $O_{X}(D)$ is sheaf of $O_{X}$-modules ?

Comment: Can you please share your thoughts on the problem, and explain what you've tried and what's giving you trouble?